# uploading two file in php without array

Tags: php

I am trying rename file before uploading them without using array, but the problem which I am facing is that the name of the file is not according to what I am mentioning here is my code

```
$path = "mande/";
  $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  $file2 = $_FILES['file1']["name"];
  $time = date('is'); // Minutes and seconds
  $newname = abc . '-' . $time; 
  $newname2 = 'letter' . 'abc' . '-' . $time; 
  $ext = strrchr($file_name, ".");
  $filename = $newname . $ext;
  $filename2 = 'letter' . $newname . $ext;
  $path = $path . $newname . $ext;
  $path2 = $path . $newname2 . $ext;
```

After using insert query i am trying to move this two by using these statements

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], $path2);
```

First file uploaded gets the exact name as per my need but the second one is having some issue, For example 
First File name: abc-1234.pdf
Second File name: abc-1234.pdfletterabc-1234.pdf INSTEAD OF letterabc-1234.pdf

Comment: change `$filename2 = 'letter' . $newname . $ext;` to `$filename2 = 'letter' . $newname2 . $ext;`

Comment: `$_FILES` is an array

Comment: @RamRaider read the title

Comment: @Sharky - I have read the title - `$_FILES` is still an array

Comment: Basically you cannot rename files before uploading them - imagine the chaos if you could manipulate files on the client without them uploading first

Comment: @RamRaider this question seems to suffer from lots of things. it looks files are already uploaded, in a strange way, using a superglobal (which has been tampered before?)

Comment: try `$path1 = $path . $newname . $ext;` and use `$path1` instead of `$path` use same logic with other variables also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1) Your path gets mixed up as you are using the same variable again and again. Make your path `$storage_path` and use that as your base path

2) change `$filename2 = 'letter' . $newname . $ext;` to `$filename2 = 'letter' . $newname2 . $ext;`

```
$storage_path = "mande/";  // FIRST PROBLEM WAS HERE
$file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file2 = $_FILES['file1']["name"];
$time = date('is'); // Minutes and seconds
$newname = abc . '-' . $time; 
$newname2 = 'letter' . 'abc' . '-' . $time; 
$ext = strrchr($file_name, ".");
$filename = $newname . $ext;
$filename2 = 'letter' . $newname2 . $ext; // SECOND PROBLEM WAS HERE
$path = $storage_path . $newname . $ext; // FIRST PROBLEM WAS HERE
$path2 = $storage_path . $newname2 . $ext; // FIRST PROBLEM WAS HERE
```

Comment: Yes, Problem solved, Thanks Dear, I fix it with your first suggestion, And Its working without changing $filename2..

Answer (score 0):

```
$abspath = "mande/";
$file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$file2 = $_FILES['file1']["name"];
$time = date('is'); // Minutes and seconds
$newname = abc . '-' . $time; 
$newname2 = 'letter' . 'abc' . '-' . $time; 
$ext = strrchr($file_name, ".");
$filename = $newname . $ext;
$filename2 = 'letter' . $newname . $ext;
$path = $abspath . $newname . $ext;
$path2 = $abspath . $newname2 . $ext;
```

Comment: U have problem with redeclare your variable.